# AdMob Ads on Android Canvas GamePanel

Tags: java, android, admob, android-canvas

I want to place an admob adbanner on a canvas surfaceview. (A Class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceView.Callback).
Any solutions to place a view on the top? For example a basic button.

Comment: Please post your layout xml!

Comment: I don't have a layout yet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to add it inside your SurfaceView, you could add it on your SurfaceView's parent ViewGroup after you add the SurfaceView.

Pseudo Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The same can also be achieved using code instead of xml...